# go ethereum bigint and unit256

Tags: golang, uint256

Golang can only handles up to 64 int however ethereum contract call can return uint256 for example https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20 balanceOf method.

Does https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum just always assume the return result is always <= 64 bits? How does it work exactly? It feel fragile to me

Answer (score 0):

I believe that go-ethereum uses [uint256 (Fixed size 256-bit math library)](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/holiman/uint256), which *is a library specialized at replacing the big.Int library for math based on 256-bit types*